# How to get ! operator to work inside while loop with multiple conditions

Tags: c#

Im trying to do a check using a while loop I want the loop to only ask the user to re-enter their value if one of three conditions are triggered. That is if the response is blank, nor a "Y" or "N". I did this by using the ! operator. I've noticed that even if the response is the correct choice the while loop still asks to re-enter a value. I also noticed that when I remove the ! operator from in front of the second condition and the user enters the right response the code after the loop block works but when i add the ! operator back to the condition the loop works even if the response is correct.

```
PromptMessage("If you are using a different download path for your mods enter (Y)es. Or if you want to exit out the" +
                " program enter (N)o!", ConsoleColor.Green);
string CustomPath = Console.ReadLine();
CustomPath.ToUpper();
Console.WriteLine(CustomPath);
while (!CustomPath.Contains("Y") || !CustomPath.Contains("N") || String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomPath))
{
    AlertMessage("Please enter either Y to continue or N to exit");                    
    CustomPath = Console.ReadLine();
    CustomPath.ToUpper();                   
}
```

Comment: Remember that strings are immutable.  So calling `.ToUpper()` does nothing on the thing you call it on, you have to assign the value to another variable.

Comment: Also, what is it you are trying to do exactly?  Is the `while` loop meant to just "validate" the response?

Comment: Yes the while loop is for validation. if the string is blank or does not contain Y or N, i want it to prompt the user to enter the correct response.

Comment: Also don't use NOT in combination with OR, it makes the code very difficult to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple things wrong here.  First, Strings are immutable in C#, so doing this:

```
string foo = "some string";
foo.ToUpper();
```

Means that `foo` is still equal to `"some string"` after running it.  You need to *assign* the value to a variable (it can even be the same variable).  Like this:

```
string foo = "some string";
foo = foo.ToUpper();
//foo = "SOME STRING"
```

The next problem is your loop and logic.  I think a much easier way to do this is using a `do/while` loop and checking the "validity" of the input in the while condition.  The `do/while` loop means you will always "do" something once before checking the `while` condition.  You always want to ask for input one time so it makes more sense to use this loop:

```
public static void Main()
{
    //defined in outer scope        
    string customPath = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("If you are using a different download path for your mods enter (Y)es. Or if you want to exit out the program enter (N)o!");
        //Calling ToUpper() before assigning the value to customPath
        customPath = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }
    while (customPath != "N" && customPath != "Y");
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZPUdm0)

Comment: Yes, i see what i did wrong and completely forgot about reassigning the variable so it could be changed using .ToUpper(). I've always had a problem with logic so thank you for showing me another way to solve my problem and clarifying.

Comment: "Y" does not equal "N" so the loop will continue if the user enters "Y". You need an `&&` not an `||` in that condition.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have your logic reversed. Do you mean to have the conditions for the `while` as follows?

```
while (!CustomPath.Contains("Y") && !CustomPath.Contains("N") && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomPath))
```

This would be logically equivalent to the following statement (but this one is much less readable IMO)

```
while (!(CustomPath.Contains("Y") || CustomPath.Contains("N") || String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomPath))
```

This way the loop will continue while the entered path does not have contain "Y", "N", or an empty path.

Also note that as @maccettura pointed out you will want to change to using `CustomPath = CustomPath.ToUpper();`

Answer (score 1):

Change into this

```
while ((!CustomPath.Contains("Y") && !CustomPath.Contains("N")) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomPath))
```

I realize that your code will always return true.

For example, you input 'Y'

```
!CustomPath.Contains("Y") => false
!CustomPath.Contains("N") => true
```

Since you use `||`, it will always return true.